# "Заказан" в значении "запрещен"

Tags: фразеология

"Туда тебе путь заказан" говорят, когда человеку куда-то нельзя. Откуда это выражение? Почему заказан?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

От более древнего значения корня "каз" - установление, требование, табу. Заказ - запрещение. Отсюда указ, наказ и проч. Современное "заказ", "заказывать" появилось от развившегося позднее значения "поручение".
Следует иметь в виду, что исторически это не омонимы, а разошедшиеся значения одного морфа, в основе которого - требование.

Answer (score 2):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ ЧЕРНЫХ. Слова с корнем КАЗ  имеют общеславянскую основу kazati, восходящую к и.-е. корню. Его старшее значение - "казаться, являться", то есть становиться видимым, проявлять себя. Затем развитие значения шло по следующей схеме: "показывать, указывать", далее (на славянской почве) - "говорить, сказать".

Можно предположить, что "заказать" в значении "запретить" - это старшее значение корня. Имеется в виду "закрыть, сделать невидимым, не показывать".

Значение "заказать - сделать заказ" - более позднее, здесь имеется в виду "указать, сделать выбор".

Comment: В Польском языке например до сих пор используется это слово. Например "zakaz palenia" - курение запрещено 

Answer (score 0):

Это ж получается одно слово используются в двух противоположных значениях- 
и запрет и требование. Такая двусмысленность всегда у меня вызывала путаницу и когнитивный диссонанс.

Comment: Запрет и требование это разные степени одного и того же, а не противоположные значения.